# Asp.net website is different when it's published.

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

It's must be CSS issues. When I'm debugging the site it's fine but published on IIS it's a mess. I edited the bootstrap file (not the .min) to apply my theme etc but when I published it, it was showing the bootstrap without the modifications.

Comment: Can you confirm that the correct CSS files are on the server after publication?

Comment: You can use your browser's developer tools to see if any assets are getting 404 errors. If they are then they are not being deployed on the server

Comment: Ok I did. It's not what I made during development.

Comment: I looked at the bootstrap.min.css and it's different.